# What happen to the electric field in depletion region of a $p-n$ junction diode in forward bias vs a no bias condition?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Does the electric field strength within the depletion region decrease as a result of a decrease in the depletion width due to forward bias vs no bias condition?

Does this electric field strength whether or not is affected by different bias condition contribute to the change in the barrier potential somehow if all other factor remains the same (i.e.: temperature, acceptor concentration, donor concentration same element)?

Comment: This generally is shown clearly in all intro texts that I know of. Yes, the field in the depletion layer changes with applied bias. Could you clarify your question?

Comment: how does the electric field affect the voltage barrier

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the electric field strength will decrease with a decrease in the width of the depletion region, that's basic electrostatics ($E = V/W$, where $V$ is the barrier potential and $W$, Depletion Layer width).

Yes, bias condition does affect the barrier potential, the OP is supposed to know this if they understand what a bias condition essentially is.

And Electric Field in a normal diode doesn't set up the voltage barrier, it's usually the other way around. The applied bias potential and condition effects the barrier potential which sets up a corresponding electric field.

Comment: The first sentence seems wrong: Since E=V/W, E will increase - not decrease - if W decreases.

Answer (score -1):

The electric field  increases but the depletion layer decreases. $v = E d$, when we compare $d$ decreases more than the increase in $E$, so the barrier potential decreases in general.